# Updating multiple (linked) datasheets on the same subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a navigation form with multiple tabs. Under one of the tabs, I have inserted several datasheets. These datasheets are all related to the same table – they simply display different fields from that table. The reason that I use multiple datasheets linked to the same table is that the table contains many fields, and I don’t want to force my users to enter data into a single “wide” datasheet. An ID column is also present in each datasheet to help the user identify the same record across the datasheets.

When I enter a new record in one of the datasheets, I want that record to be displayed in the other datasheets as well. My problem is that a record entered in one of the datasheets will not instantly be visible in the other datasheets. I have to close the form and open it again, and only then is the record displayed in all of the datasheets.

I tried to solve the problem by inserting a requery statement in the After Update event of the datasheet, but this makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Is each of the "datasheets" a subform?  Have you tried doing a subformname.requery for each one?  (Can't remember if this can be done for just the main form)

Comment: It works now. I had to reference the subform rather than the datasheet, i.e. Forms![MainForm]![SubForm_1].Form.Requery.

Comment: cool.  glad to see it worked.